# How to put EditText that filters a list in the menubar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have an EditText that filters a list. When user starts typing in the list the list gets filtered. However, this field is showing above the list. However, I want it to show in the menu bar when the "search" icon is clicked.

Here is how the screen looks:

[image]

Here is how screen looks when search icon is clicked

[image]

The functionality that "Type something here" achieves, I want it to be moved to the `EditText` that shows up when user clicks the search icon (second screenshot)

Here is my layout for this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        style="@style/FormalSingleLineEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/sometext" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

For the search Icon I am using ActionbarSherlock:

```
menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.search)
        .setActionView(R.layout.collapsible_edittext)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
```

Comment: "I want the EditText that says "Type something here" to move to when user clicks Search icon." i guess there is some sort of spelling/word issue here, might wanna fix that because i dont know what you want to do :)

Comment: Yeah, didn't make much sense. I've updated now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a seachview if you want the search edittext to appear in the action bar. Check this link.
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/10/20/actionbar-search-option-options-android/